# How to use MySql 'Insert Ignore into' query to insert records based on some values from a different table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables as below. The Id column value in both the tables mentioned below is auto-incremented.

**LoginInfo**
`+----+------------+-------------+`
| `Id  |` `LoginName |`     `IP         |`
`+------+----------+-------------+`
|  `1   |` `User1     |` `aa.bb.cc.dd|`
|  `2   |` `User2     |` `xx.xx.xx.xx|`
|  `3   |` `User3     |` `ii.ii.ii.ii|`
`+----+------------+-------------+`

**UserGroups**
`+----+------------+-------------+`
| `Id  |` `LoginName |`     `Groups     |`
`+------+----------+-------------+`
|  `1   |` `User1     |` `Group1     |`
|  `2   |` `User1     |` `Default    |`
|  `3   |` `User2     |` `Group2     |`
|  `4   |` `User3     |` `Group3     |`
`+----+------------+-------------+`

Each of the user in **LoginInfo** table should be a member of 'Default' group in **UserGroups** table. So in the above table User1 is associated to 'Default' group but User2 and User3 are not.

I would like to check whether 'Default' group entry is added for each of the User in **UserGroups** table. If available Ignore Insert, else Insert a new record for that User.

The mysql query which I tried is
`INSERT IGNORE INTO USERGROUPS(LOGINNAME, GROUPS) SELECT LOGINNAME, 'Default' FROM LOGININFO L WHERE L.IP IS NOT NULL;`
After execution, the message displayed as 3 rows affected and the **UserGroups** table look like

`+----+------------+-------------+`
| `Id  |` `LoginName |`     `Groups     |`
`+------+----------+-------------+`
|  `1   |` `User1     |` `Group1     |`
|  `2   |` `User1     |` `Default    |`
|  `3   |` `User2     |` `Group2     |`
|  `4   |` `User3     |` `Group3     |`
|  `5   |` `User1     |` `Default    |`
|  `6   |` `User2     |` `Default    |`
|  `7   |` `User3     |` `Default    |`
`+----+------------+-------------+`

But what I actually look for is as below

`+----+------------+-------------+`
| `Id  |` `LoginName |`     `Groups     |`
`+------+----------+-------------+`
|  `1   |` `User1     |` `Group1     |`
|  `2   |` `User1     |` `Default    |`
|  `3   |` `User2     |` `Group2     |`
|  `4   |` `User3     |` `Group3     |`
|  `5   |` `User2     |` `Default    |`
|  `6   |` `User3     |` `Default    |`
`+----+------------+-------------+`

Please let know suggestions on the query or any workarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add an unique constraint before executing INSERT IGNORE:

```
ALTER TABLE UserGroups ADD UNIQUE (LoginName, Groups)
```

then you can execute this query:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO USERGROUPS(LOGINNAME, GROUPS)
SELECT LOGINNAME, 'Default'
FROM LOGININFO
WHERE IP IS NOT NULL
```

Please see this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eaf3d8/1).

Comment: This is logical and now I understand the use of INSERT IGNORE. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

You can form the `SELECT` part of the `INSERT` statement in a way that duplicate records are filtered out:

```
INSERT INTO UserGroups(LoginName, Groups) 
SELECT LoginName, 'Default' 
FROM LoginInfo AS l 
WHERE l.IP IS NOT NULL 
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM UserGroups AS ug
                      WHERE ug.LoginName = l.LoginName AND ug.Groups = 'Default');
```

You then don't need to use `IGNORE`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01d61/1)

Comment: It worked. Thanks :) So in this case, We need not alter the table to add unique constraint right. Just curious to know any advantage of using `INSERT IGNORE` than normal `INSERT`.

Comment: @Murali I think you should add that unique constraint anyway, so as to guarantee data integrity. Perhaps my query is more efficient as it attempts to insert less values compared to the query using `INSERT IGNORE`. You can tell us how these two compare when you use them with your actual data.

Comment: Yes the actual tables which would be used might have huge no of records. Currently I do not have the setup. I shall get the results based on some numbers once I get the setup.